# R: How to replace single columns of a table in database

Tags: sql, r, database

Does anyone know a workaround for replacing a single column in a table on a MS SQL Server database?

The point is that, due to memory restrictions, I want to avoid to pull the entire table into my R-Session. Instead of dbWriteTable(), can one only (over)write a colum?

What would also help was an appropriate query that can be taken to the database via dbSendQuery() and that takes into account the new column to be tranferred to the database.

To make things clearer, I add some code describing what I am searching for:

```
# pull "someColumn" and "identifier" from "databaseTable"
dplyr::tbl(odbConnection, dbplyr::in_schema("schemaName", "databaseTable")) %>% 
  select(identifier, someColumn) %>% 
  dplyr::collect() -> data2beUpdated

# update "someColumn" accoring to a "lookupTable" in R-session also having the "identifier"
data2beUpdated$newColumn <- lookupTable[match(data2beUpdated$identifier, lookupTable$identifier), "newValues"]

apply(data2beUpdated,
      1,
      FUN = function(x){ ifelse(
        is.na(x["newValues"]),
        x["someColumn"],
        x["newValues"] 
      )#ifelse
        }#fun
      ) -> data2beUpdated$someColumn

# now write back the data in the way I DON'T want to do it since it costs runtime to pull in the entire data table
dplyr::tbl(odbConnection, dbplyr::in_schema("schemaName", "databaseTable")) %>%  
  dplyr::collect() -> df

df$someColumn <- data2beUpdated$someColumn

DBI::dbWriteTable(odbcConnection, "databaseTable", df, overwrite = TRUE)
```

Any suggestions?!

Comment: What do you mean "replace"?  Just select the columns that you *do* want.

Comment: Please show us what the update query looks like.  Does it involve any data which exists locally in your R session?  If it does, then you might be stuck with reading the entire table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Guess they want to change the values of a column. Something like `df[,oldCol:=newValues]` with `data.table`. The problem here is that database engine are often row based and so one cannot just tell "put these values in the column", since row orders is often irrelevant. OP, describe the logic to replace the values.

Comment: @nicola I see the problem from the point of view that the OP might want to avoid having to read the SQL table into R memory in the first place.  That is, if an update could be executed remotely on the SQL server, that might be preferable.

Comment: @all: Right, the data that serves as the replacement is in a local R session. One might think of one column of a database table to be updated according to a lookup table that is created in a local R session. I pull the respective column from the database, make the changes and then, instead of pulling, updating and writing back the whole data table, I would like to replace solely the updated column. Do you see any solution?